# Backing up database via php script and odbc

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

The database array variable is this:

```
$_CONFIG['db_databases'] = array(                                                           // Datenbanken
        'acc' => 'ACCOUNT_DBF',
        'chr' => 'CHARACTER_01_DBF',
        'web' => 'WEBSITE_DBF',
        'log' => 'LOGGING_01_DBF',
        'eocrm' => 'EoCRM_DBF',
        'eocrm_r' => 'EoCRM_DBF_R',
        'itm' => 'ITEM_DBF',
        'mng' => 'MANAGE_DBF',
        'rnk' => 'RANKING_DBF',
    );
```

---

The path variable is this:

```
$_CONFIG['db_backup_path'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\extras\Backups - Database';
```

---

So here is my full code of the back up function that loops through each database in the array 'db_databases'.

```
foreach($_CONFIG['db_databases'] as $type => $strNameOfDatabase) {
        if($type != 'log') {
            if(@odbc_exec($odbc_connect, "
                BACKUP DATABASE [$strNameOfDatabase]
                TO DISK = '" . $_CONFIG['db_backup_path'] . "\\" . date('Y') . "\\" . date('m') . "\\$date-$strNameOfDatabase.bak'
                WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'$strNameOfDatabase - Full Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
            ")) {
                $notifyArray[] = "Success: Back up of [$strNameOfDatabase]";
            }
            else {
                $notifyArray[] = "Error: Back up of [$strNameOfDatabase]";
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not have any idea why it is not doing the job. I tried to execute the same script into my mssql 2014 manually and it executed and backed up the database fine. Is there any wrong with the path or something?

Comment: Why do you need to do this versus using the tools built into SSMS?

Comment: I made an administration panel iny my website and it is just one of the features of the administration panel that backs up databases in the databases array.

Comment: What error do you get?